# jQuery .change function only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Using jQuery 1.11.1 and this snippet of code to detect a change to the value of a select field and then running some script off of it. It works once and then will not work a second time. It's gets far enough to remove the 'visible' class and that's it.

```
var oatChoice;

$('#cereal').change(function(){

    oatChoice = ($(this).val());

    $('.oats').removeClass('visible').delay(1000).queue(function() {
        imageURL = '/assets/images/layers/oats-' + oatChoice;
        imgSwitch('.oats',imageURL);
        $('.oats').addClass('visible');
    });

});

imgSwitch = function(div,imgURL){
    $(div + ' img').remove();
    $(div).append('<img src="' + imgURL + '.png"/>');
}
```

I'm running this code on this bit of html below:

```
<div class="layer oats">
    <img src="/assets/images/layers/oats-applecinnamon.png" alt="">
</div>

<select name="cereal" id="cereal" class="form-control">
    <option value="">- Select A Cereal -</option>
    <option value="applecinnamon">Apple Cinnamon Oatmeal</option>
    <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
</select>
```

I created a fiddle here.. http://jsfiddle.net/aehj289o/1/ Images are missing but you can see that it quits working after the first go around.

Comment: can you post your code in a JS FIDDLE?

Comment: `.change()` is limited to `<select>`, `<input>`, and `<textarea>`. What are you listening for a change on? Is there more HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#cereal').unbind('change').change(function(){

    //the rest of your code

})
```

Edit: You might try taking your vars and functions out of the global scope, and re-rendering the function with each change action, like this:

```
(function(main, $, undefined){

    Template = {
        oatChoice:null,
        render: function(){
            Template.setup.changeActions();
        }
        setup: {
            changeActions : function(){
               $('#cereal').unbind('change').change(function(){
                   Template.oatChoice = ($(this).val());
                    $('.oats').removeClass('visible').delay(1000).queue(function() {
                        imageURL = '/assets/images/layers/oats-' + Template.oatChoice;
                        Template.imgSwitch('.oats',imageURL);
                        $('.oats').addClass('visible');
                    });
                    Template.render();
                });
            }
        },
        imgSwitch : function(div,imgURL){
            $(div + ' img').remove();
            $(div).append('<img src="' + imgURL + '.png"/>');
        },
    }

}(window.main = window.main || {}, jQuery));
```